# Where to store data of Windows Service (run as Local System)?

Tags: windows, windows-services

According to [Technical requirements for the Windows 7 Client Software Logo Program](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3859) (and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163611/where-is-the-guideline-that-says-you-shouldnt-write-to-the-program-files-area)), application/user data should be saved under the AppData directory, and never under `Program Files` or `Windows`.

But what if the application is a Windows Service running as Local System? Should the data be stored under `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData`?

Comment: This may be of interest; http://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou

Comment: Yep that's how I found systemprofile\AppData. Just curious if that's the right place to store the data (since %APPDATA% goes there).

Comment: I can't find anything in the logo certification documents that would forbid or even discourage using `%APPDATA%` if it's actually set for a local system account. That's all I have for now, sorry :)

Comment: I think that's good for me. Thanks Joachim =)